# What happens when you update an Windows store app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

What happens when a developer updates an app? Does the user that updates the said app download a whole new app or is the windows app store smart enough like play store to just download the changes?Can anyone give logical explanation how it works in windows store?

Answer (score 1):

***>>Does the user that updates the said app download a whole new app or is the windows app store smart enough like play store to just download the changes?***

When the developers created package for their project, and chose **generate app bundle always**, the user can download faster with an app bundle, because they only download the assets that they need. Then they don’t need to download a whole new app to update. If the developers didn’t choose this, the user may need to download a whole new app.

***>>Can anyone give logical explanation how it works in windows store?***

For example, if you create a app, then you choose generate app bundle always when packaging your app and publish this in the Windows Store. The customer need to download 100MB to require this app. After a period of time, you update this app, the customer just download the assets that they need to update our app, maybe just download 10MB.